# Eventarc google.cloud.scheduler.v1beta1.CloudScheduler.RunJob not being triggered

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a trigger on Eventarc that is supposed to run after each Cloud Scheduler invocation, which is `google.cloud.scheduler.v1beta1.CloudScheduler.RunJob`

However, it is not being triggered anyhow!

Other triggers, like **force run**, are working.

I want to trigger a Cloud Run after a Job execution. Is it possible or I am facing a bug?

[image]

Comment: Did you activate the audit logs?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere does the Cloud Scheduler have Audit Logs? Which audit logs I need to activate?

Comment: My bad, no audit logs (it's a common mistake that's why I asked without checking....) No clues... Are you in the same region? do you filter the logs  and exclude the schedulers logs?

Comment: All are in the same region, everything is on us-central1. I do not filter any logs; it is a new application. Do I need to filter? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are expecting your Cloud Run service to be executed at each scheduled invocation of Cloud Scheduler, it isn't possible to do so through Eventarc **and** Cloud Audit logs.

This is due to Cloud Scheduler not being in the list of services that [write audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/services). Adding to that, the [`RunJob`](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.jobs/run) event you are filtering by will only get written if you manually execute a job (using the API), and not by your set CRON schedule.

A manual job run did trigger Eventarc when I tested this scenario, but I had to [set my trigger as global](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/locations).

If you would like to execute the Cloud Run service on a schedule, you can do that by having Cloud Scheduler [send a request](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/using-scheduler) to the service URL directly. Another alternative is to instead of having Eventarc listen to Audit logs, have it listen to [messages on a Pub/Sub topic](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/run/pubsub-authenticated), which will be [sent by Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating#create). Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: +1 , For reference, here's the full list of Cloud Scheduler events that EventArc supports. There isn't one (yet) that detects the cronjob scheduled run: https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/reference/supported-events#cloud-scheduler

Comment: Also, if you're going the EventArc route, it's all powered by Pub/sub, which means that if your cloudrun execution fails, the pubsub subscription will attempt to retry sending the event (it retries a minimum of 5 times, if u have a dead-letter queue). Be prepared to implement an idempotent request handler if using EventArc. In general, you should anyway, though it is less obvious with a direct CloudScheduler -> HTTP -> Cloudrun invocation.

Comment: I am using Cloud Scheduler with AppEngine, is it possible to listen for the events? Thanks!

Comment: For App Engine you're able to [directly send a request from Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating#create:~:text=job%20will%20publish.-,App%20Engine%20HTTP,-%3A%20you%20must%20use), or have the application [listen for Pub/Sub messages](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/writing-and-responding-to-pub-sub-messages#creating_a_topic_and_subscription) from Scheduler. Eventarc would not be available here, as App Engine is not a [supported target](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/targets).